# How to document params that can be one of type a, b, c, n

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have been looking for a way to document this in js:

```
function foo(param1: 'opt1' | 'opt2') { ... }
```

But found nothing because I don't know how can I search for it and didn't find any example alike to what I want to do in JSDoc

I have tried with:

```
/**
* @param {string} param1 - Receives either 'opt1' | 'opt2'
*/
function foo(param1) { ... };
```

But I think there would be a better way to specify if `param1` receives a string that's either 'these' or 'that'. Another solution than only put in the param description what you can pass as value like shown in my example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702556/enum-as-param-type-in-jsdoc might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can document your function this way in case of strings:

```
/**
* @param {('opt1' | 'opt2')} param1
*/
function foo(param1) { };
```

Using the same method you can also handle integer values

```
/**
* @param {(1 | 2)} param1
*/
function foo(param1) { };
```

This will allow editors to give suggestions using the documented values like following

[image]

Comment: That was easier than what i thought, thanks pal!